# How do dragand drop an system__ComObject

Tags: vb.net, image, drag-and-drop

I am trying to use drag and drop images between two programs. In the sending app

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown
        If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
            Dim drop_effect As DragDropEffects = PictureBox1.DoDragDrop(PictureBox1.Image, DragDropEffects.Copy)
        End If
    End Sub
```

And the receiving app

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.DragEnter
        If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap, True) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        ElseIf e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        End If
    End Sub

Private Sub PictureBox1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.DragDrop
    If e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Bitmap) Then
        PictureBox1.Image =DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap), Image)
    ElseIf e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
        Dim files() As String = DirectCast(e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
        Dim Bait = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(files(0))
    End If
End Sub
```

The drop stop with a long message

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to class type 'System.Drawing.Image'. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to types that do not represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.'

I have found a lot of examples on the internet and had tried them. Those who passed compile gave the same error.
The variation I tried was to change the direct cast to try cast or no cast at all.
Please help and use VB.

Comment: Getting exceptions is quite normal, but it is not supposed to stop.  You need to reset the debugger so it won't interrupt your testing session.  In VS2017+ use Debug > Windows > Exception Settings and untick the boxes.

Comment: If you don't want to deal with these two OLE guys here: [FORMATETC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.formatetc) and [STGMEDIUM](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comtypes.stgmedium), I suggest you add your own format (it's just a string, you can use whatever you want, the receiver app just needs to know this format exists) and send the Bitmap as a byte array (save the Image to a MemoryStream, then send `[MemoryStream.ToArray()]`, get `Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream([bytes]))` on the other side).

Comment: I am not looking for a bypass, creating my own format or using the clipboard, which I am going to add anyway.

Comment: I am looking for an answer, why this procedure that is shown a dozen times works and does not in this case.

Comment: Since your Image is not serialized, when you drag outside the current application scope, the Bitmap object goes *into the wild*. This triggers the standard Interop functionality, achieved through COM packaging. Any Windows application that allows interaction with foreign application needs to handle COM Interop in a way or another, at some point. Or use a well-know custom format. Or multiple well-known formats, as it happens if you try to Drag objects from an Office application or a Web Browser application: you'll see data passed on in 10-20 different formats.

Comment: If you want to send and handle a Bitmap object directly, without any form of serialization, you have to handle the COM package. If you're interested, I can show you how this is done. But, as already mentioned, you could add your own format, simply passing the Bitmap object as a byte array. The `IDataObject` (the `e.Data` object provided by `DragEventArgs` in a `DragDrop` event) can set multiple formats and any custom format is allowed, as long as the receiving application knows how to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

In reviewing the [source code for the DataObject Class](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataObject.cs,9130c7eaac36fe2e), it becomes apparent that this class is designed to handle COM based IDataObject instances.  To access this ability you need to construct a new `DataObject` instance and passing the `IDataObject` provided by the `DragEventArgs`.

From [DataObject(Object) documentation's Remarks section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataobject.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_DataObject__ctor_System_Object_):

> You can add data in any format to the DataObject when you use this constructor, or you can add data as an IDataObject to provide multiple formats at once. If you are familiar with COM programming, you can also add a data object that implements the COM IDataObject interface.

With that information, your drop handler can be rewritten as follows:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.DragDrop
  Dim localDataObject As DataObject = New DataObject(e.Data)

  If localDataObject.ContainsImage Then
    PictureBox1.Image = localDataObject.GetImage
  ElseIf localDataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop) Then
    Dim files() As String = DirectCast(localDataObject.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop), String())
    Dim bytes As Byte() = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllBytes(files(0))
  End If
End Sub
```